# Python dpkt packet analysis

Tags: python, tcp, pcap

I'm wanting to find the timestamping from pcap file using **python dpkt** package; similar to **tcpdump -tttt** option which would provide me the **details of *time with date* of the packet that was generated**.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could provide some code snippet in your question. A rough guess is that you can try something like this:

```
myPcap = open('test.pcap')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(myPcap)
for ts in pcap:
   print ts
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by importing the datetime package.

```
import dpkt

import datetime

for ts, buf in pcap:
  eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet()

//this is the method that is used to convert the epoch time to date

date1=**datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')**

//rest of the code can go after this
```